# replace phrases in a file without over duplicate

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a file which contains a parallel texts: source and target texts. From  the source text I extracted some expressions and I want to replace these expressions in the source text but in different format, such as using square brackets.

this is an example of the file

```
</seg>
<seg match="1-1" id="2">
<src>Difensori dei diritti umani e organizzazioni sono stati oggetto di crescenti intimidazioni e minacce in un clima di limitazione della libertà di espressione, che ha anche visto un giornalista incarcerato per diversi mesi.</src>
<tgt>تعرض عدد من المدافعين عن حقوق الإنسان والمنظمات المعنية بحقوق الإنسان للترهيب والتهديد بصورة متزايدة، وسط مناخ من القيود على حرية التعبير، شهد أيضاً الحكم بسجن أحد الصحفيين لعدة أشهر.</tgt>
</seg>
<seg match="1-1" id="3">
<src>Sono stati riportati casi di sgomberi forzati e violazioni dei diritti umani da parte della polizia, ma su scala minore rispetto agli anni precedenti.</src>
<tgt>ووردت أنباء عن حالات من الإجلاء القسري وانتهاكات حقوق الإنسان على أيدي الشرطة، وإن كان ذلك على نطاق أقل من مثيله في السنوات السابقة.</tgt>
</seg>
<seg match="1-1" id="4">
<src>Una rivolta carceraria nella Prigione centrale di Luanda ha determinato morti e feriti, sebbene le cifre a tal riguardo siano state contestate.</src>
<tgt>وأسفر تمرد للسجناء في سجن لواندا المركزي عن سقوط قتلى وجرحى، ولكن أعداد الضحايا كانت موضع خلاف.</tgt
```

and this an example of the expressions that I want to replace in the source text

```
libertà di espressione, sgomberi forzati, rivolta carceraria
```

this is the code that I used

```
ex = codecs.open('filedirectory','r',encoding='utf-8').read().split(',')
parallel_text = codecs.open('filedirectory', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
parallel = parallel_text.splitlines()

for line in parallel:
    if line.startswith('<src>'):
        source = line
        for l in ex:
            if l in source:
               newcorpus= parallel_text.replace(l, "[" + l + "]")  
               print newcorpus
```

This code gives an over duplicates and in some lines does not replace
Can someone help?

Comment: If you extract this from xml, use an xml parser to parse it for you. Don't parse it manually.

Comment: I extracted from the source text before the alignment, so I did not use xml to extract. And I do not know how to use xml parser to replace

Comment: What is the expected output (I get nothing from `print`)? For a nicer implementation, read here on Python's ElementTree: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: How can I do it in ElementTree?

Comment: If your original document was in xml format, than yes. parse that document using the library and use the result as you want.

Comment: Yes, but for replacing what must I do?

Comment: You need to read the tutorial and understand how xml parsing works :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is something to get you started with what I could understand from the question, in case you don't move to an xml parser like [element tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
# coding=utf-8
import codecs
import os

parallel_text = codecs.open('./1/filedirectory', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
parallel = parallel_text.splitlines()

to_be_replaced = [
    u"libertà di espressione",
    u"sgomberi forzati",
    u"rivolta carceraria"
]

result = []

for line in parallel:
    if line.startswith('<src>'):
        for s in to_be_replaced:
            if s in line:
                line = line.replace(s, '[' + s + ']')
        result.append(line)

print os.linesep.join(result)
```

Comment: If you want to write a change in an existing file, you have to re-write the file. if you have a new bug with your program post a questino stating what exactly is the problem, what is the input that's not working, and what is the output you're expecting.